# Was the launch of "Tianhe" a failure or success?

Tags: china

Recently on April 29 2021,  Chinese space program launched [Tianhe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe_(space_station_module)) as part of [Tiangong space station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station). In [launch section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe_(space_station_module)#Launch) it states the mission was **failure**:

> Tianhe launched on 29 April 2021, at 03:23:15 UTC atop a Long March 5B
> launch vehicle from the  Wenchang Spacecraft Launch Site. After the
> core module was put into orbit, the launch vehicle entered a
> **temporary, uncontrolled failing orbit**.

But in [List of mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station#List_of_missions), it is declared a **success**.

Comment: You are misreading. It was the launch vehicle that went into an uncontrolled orbit that will eventually reenter. That does not mean the mission was a failure. The mission apparently went exactly as planned, with the payload (Tianhe) successfully placed into the designed orbit. China has made a calculated bet that the uncontrolled reentry of the launch vehicle (which is no longer needed for mission success) won't result in significant damage. It's a somewhat reasonable bet as most of the Earth's surface is ocean, and most of the Earth's land area is sparsely populated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've answered your question yourself.

The launch placed the space station's core module into orbit. Hence it was a success. However, the vehicle consisted of more than just the core module. The Long March 5 rocket consists of several stages, the last one of which (the "launch vehicle") was left in an orbit that would bring it back to earth in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: Which, unfortunately, seems to be just how the CZ-5B is designed, given that the last one also reentered uncontrolled. So, not only does this launch seem to be successful, it also seems to be nominal.